# Why does Marshal.GetExceptionPointers return IntPtr.Zero and what can I do about it?

Tags: c#

The questions that may already have my answer didn't include my question, so here goes.

I am making a call from managed code, C#.  In the catch section, I am attempting to call Marshal.GetExceptionPointers in a 32-bit process.  This returns IntPtr.Zero every time.
When running the same code in 64-bit, it works properly and returns the proper exception pointers.
Does anyone understand the reasons for this and how to retrieve the exception pointers in the 32-bit side?

Thank you

Comment: I suppose one would wonder why you would be calling this

Comment: Did you already see [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/f2070292-550e-41cd-a223-a46be136adb8/getexceptionpointers-returns-intptrzero-for-net-x86-application-on-windows-7-x64?forum=csharpgeneral)?

Comment: For Mr. Heffernan, we do this to write out a mini dump that will get us right to the point of a fatal exception.  For #1, Thank you.  I have seen that link, but it did not provide a solution.  Helped me understand the problem better, but not a solution so far as I can see for C#.

Comment: C# doesn't have the equivalent of VB.NET's Catch When until version 6.  Don't use try/catch, use the AppDomain.UnhandledException event instead.  When it fires you always have a good reason to create a minidump.

Comment: Thank you for that Hans, I will take a look at that to see if I can leverage it.

Comment: After some research, I am unable to go the route of using the AppDomain.UnhandledException event.  Thank you for the suggestion, and I learned something from it so that was great.  I think I'm going to have to figure out how to get the pointers from the catch.